# Open and read a Outlook DBX file

Tags: outlook

What would you recommend I use to open `.DBX` files from an old Outlook Email? I want to read and copy and paste to a word program to archive.

Comment: I'd start with a simple [Google Search for "dbx reader"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dbx+reader). Tons of results. Tried any of those?